# Get product variation id by their product attributes slug values pairs in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How can I get product variation ID by taxonomy terms?

For example if I have two taxonomies and their terms:

```
1) Size: medium, large
2) Color: blue, green
```

And my product variations:

```
Variation id 1: medium > blue
Variation id 2: medium > green
Variation id 3: large > blue
Variation id 4: large > green
```

I would like to get variation ID of this terms combination `medium > green`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following function uses a very light SQL query to get the variation ID for from a variable product for defined product attributes "color" and "size" term slugs:

```
function get_product_variation_id( $size, $color, $product_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( $product_id == 0 )
        $product_id = get_the_id();

    return $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT p.ID
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_color'
        AND pm.meta_value LIKE '$color'
        AND pm2.meta_key = 'attribute_pa_size'
        AND pm2.meta_value LIKE '$size'
        AND p.post_parent = $product_id
    " );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

USAGE *(2 cases examples)*:

1. From a defined variable product ID (where `746` is the parent variable product ID):

   $variation_id = get_product_variation_id( 'large', 'blue', 746 );
2. On the variable product single product page *(No need to define the variable product ID)*:

   $variation_id = get_product_variation_id( 'large', 'blue' );

Comment: Thanks you again Loic - you made my day :-)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested but this should be nearly there or ready to ship.

```
function get_variation_by($size, $color) {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => -1,
  );
  $product_posts = get_posts( $args );

  foreach ( $product_posts as $single_product_post ) {
    $_product = wc_get_product( $single_product_post->ID );
    if ($product_s->product_type != 'variable') continue;

    $avail_vars = $_product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ($avail_vars as $v)
      if ($v["attributes"]["attribute_pa_size"] == $size
          && $v["attributes"]["attribute_pa_color"] == $color)
        return $v;
  }
  return null;
}

$variation = get_variation_by( "large", "green");
$variation_id = $variation->variation_id;
```

If you have the product_id of the variable product already, you can simplify like this:

```
function get_variation_by($variable_product_id, size, $color) {
  $var_prod = wc_get_product( $variable_product_id );        
  $avail_vars = $var_prod->get_available_variations();

  foreach ($avail_vars as $v)
    if ($v["attributes"]["attribute_pa_size"] == $size
        && $v["attributes"]["attribute_pa_color"] == $color)
      return $v;

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the product_id, but this is not cost-effective method because the loop my be very long.